# consequences of increasing max_result_window on elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

we have an index which default `max_result_window` was set up to `10000`, but our data is increasing and we expect we have more than 1 Million Docs there, on of our requirements is scroll all data from the start to end  with 1000 in each epic , our documents are not very big and I'll write down one example on following :

```
{
"serp_query": "c=44444&ct=333333",
"uid": "5815697",
"notify_status": 0,
"created_at": "2018-02-04 10:00:00"
}
```

I've set `max_result_window` to `10,000,000` but at this time we have almost  50K docs in our Index, I've read the some texts about consequences of this increasing

> Values higher than can consume significant chunks of heap memory per
>   search and per shard executing the search. It’s safest to leave this
>   value as it is an use the scroll api for any deep scrolling
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/breaking_21_search_changes.html#_from_size_limits

**But** we our Documents are not too big and our Elastic Server has 16GB dedicated RAM and guess there is not problem, 
**I'm writing  to ask**  two questions,

- according to the sample Doc ( all our docs should have the same fields) how much it could be Big for one  Million Docs,I mean how much heap memory will needed for handle this?
- is it very bad solution and will faced us with big problem in future ? are we use scrolling instead of offset and start?

our query is not very complicated, loop on all data ordered by "created_at" descending and get 1000 Docs in each epic.

**FYI:** our elastic search engine version in 2.7

Comment: Scroll should not be used for real-time search requests. You should probably investigate the [`search_after` feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html).

Comment: @Val thank you for attention, do you have any idea about the size? do you think our solution is tribble?

Comment: Even if it would work, you'll eventually come to a situation where it won't anymore and you'll have to refactor it all. So your best bet is to make sure your implemented solution is durable so you can focus on other value-added stuff.

Comment: @Val our max data is about 2-3 Million and we archive data every 2 months.

Comment: The best way to figure it out is to try it out. Load an index with production data 8same mapping, same amount), then try to load test that index and see what happens. If it works for you, then go for it. Elastic issues a general note of warning against increasing the window size, but it doesn't mean that it will never work for anyone. Everyone's settings are different, so it might definitely work out for you. No one can tell except you after some serious testing.

Comment: @Val thanks, we're going to test it .I'll comment later on this question and will inform you.

Comment: @YusefMohamadi Waiting for your comment :)

Comment: @Rakmo because our query was not very complicated and our document was simple, hopefully, we did not have an issue with increasing it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to share the Result with others,

If the Document is not very big and your queries are not very complicated increasing `max_result_window` has not big effect on performance.